# Автоматическая генерация уникальных ключей для словаря python, Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, словари

Делаю в Django калькулятор. В нем нужно реализовать историю вычислений. Историю планирую хранить в словаре. В значении будет экземпляр класса, хранящий само выражение, ответ на него и дату подсчета. Не могу определиться с ключом: мне он нужен уникальный, чтобы одно выражение не смогло затереть другое, при этом самогенерирующийся, т.е. пользователь не должен дополнительно вводить ключ, он должен сам откуда то браться. Подскажите, как можно решить проблему с ключом?

Comment: Для истории не нужен словарь, достаточно просто списка. Если прямо хочется словарь, используйте, например дату-время как ключ.

Comment: Ну или uuid генерируйте

Answer (score 0):

1. Целое число, начать с 1 и инкрементировать для каждой записи. Так делается в некоторых базах данных.
2. Timestamp любой подходящей точности.